# What do art injury, bad golfer, and pizza have in common

Tags: mystery

I have been tying to figure it out but I can't so I need help

Comment: Hi @Emily, welcome to Puzzling SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already! Unfortunately, there are several issues with your question as it is right now - it appears to be a question you did not create yourself, so it requires proper attribution; and there do not seem to be enough details to identify a single most valid answer. If you can add more details to your question, that would be great. I hope this helps!

Comment: Par.  Subpar, above par, pizza parlor

Answer (score 2):

It seems as if the answer is

> **slice**

Reasoning:

> A bad golfer *slices* his shots, and a pizza is divided into *slices*.
> But I'm not a huge fan of "art injury" as a clue for this.